# LDAP FBA Authentication and user profiles

Tags: 2010, forms-authentication, user-profile-property, ldap

I have a web app that uses FBA and LDAP (Active Directory). Users are able to login to the site without any issue. As part of on boarding process, users are redirected to their mysite "edit profile" page where they have to fill in some basic info. The issues on this page:

- **Name** property is automatically filled out as i:0#.f|ldapmember|test@test.com
- **Work Email** is not automatically filled out

During debugging I noticed, user's my settings page (/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?Force=True), show email address as their "name" and "work email" is also set to email address. This is valid for short period of time until the user profile to site sync timer job runs and then the values get updated according to their user profile.

My question is how can I:

- Automatically set a user's **Name** profile property to their name in AD (Smith, John)
- Set their **Work Email** to their email address

Also, I don't want to setup UPS for this web app as the requirement is to allow users to update their information.

Following is the ldap configuration

```
<add name="LdapMember" 
    type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
    server="xxxx.xxxx.com" 
    port="389" useSSL="false" 
    userDNAttribute="distinguishedName" 
    userNameAttribute="userPrincipalName" 
    userContainer="dc=xxxx,dc=com" 
    userObjectClass="person" 
    userFilter="(ObjectClass=person)" 
    scope="Subtree" 
    otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn" />
```

Thanks and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to get those user profile property populated automatically, so I went with a custom development approach where on the first login to the site the current user's profile is create programmatically using the following code:

```
private static void CreateProfile(UserProfileManager upm, SPUser user) {
        var profile = upm.CreateUserProfile(user.LoginName);
        profile.DisplayName = user.Email;
        profile[PropertyConstants.WorkEmail].Value = user.Email;
        profile.Commit();
}
```

For now I am filling in the user's display name as their email because that is readily available but I could get their full name from AD...